# Having member function name same as structure name

Tags: php, oop

What is this means to be in structure

```
struct book
{
  function book($name, $price)
  {
    name = $name;
    price = $price;
  }
}
$Book = new book("ANSI C", 218.00);
```

Regardless of language used in the code either it is in PHP or C, what is the meaning of code. 
It seems to be the code will assign the name and price of the book to structure, but if so, what it should be called...Constructor? I don't know about this, but I think constructor is concept of OOPs and structure comes before OOPs

Comment: This calls the constructor : http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.constructor.php of the book class in PHP. Please do not tag this is any other language because it's only valid PHP code, that is if you change your `struct` to a `class`.

Comment: Looks like a hybrid of `C` *(because of struct)*, `Javascript` *(because of function)* and PHP or Perl *(because of $)*.

Comment: In PHP, it would be an __old__ PHP4 constructor; modern PHP code should always use `__construct()` for the constructor

Comment: @Nawaz `function` is also used in PHP, struct just isnt.

Comment: @JameyD: Ohh... maybe, I did once write PHP, back in my college, so don't remember it well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If I follow C coding style i.e. variable declaration like in C, then does code will run?

Comment: @JamesD Yes. This will be OOPs constructor if I use  `class` instead of `struct`. Does this valid for struct?